# .Xml help doesn't display parameter placeholders in SYNTAX section

Tags: xml, powershell, maml

I have a **PowerShell** function in a `.ps1` file. The function has two parameter sets with one parameter each. The `param()` block in the function declaration is:

```
Function Restore-ExplorerWindow
{
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ByPath',
            Mandatory,
            Position=0,
            ValueFromPipeline)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Leaf'})]
        [String[]]
        $Path,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'ByObject',
            Mandatory,
            Position=0,
            ValueFromPipeline)]
        [System.Object[]]
        $ExplorerState
    )
```

Without any help defined, **PowerShell** generates the following:

```
SYNTAX
    Restore-ExplorerWindow [-Path] <string[]>  [<CommonParameters>]

    Restore-ExplorerWindow [-ExplorerState] <Object[]>  [<CommonParameters>]


PARAMETERS
    -ExplorerState <Object[]>

        Required?                    true
        Position?                    0
        Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue)
        Parameter set name           ByObject
        Aliases                      None
        Dynamic?                     false

    -Path <string[]>

        Required?                    true
        Position?                    0
        Accept pipeline input?       true (ByValue)
        Parameter set name           ByPath
        Aliases                      None
        Dynamic?                     false
```

But when I specify a seemingly functional .xml help file, which has the following `SYNTAX` and `PARAMETERS` nodes:

```
    <command:syntax>
      <command:syntaxItem>
        <maml:name>Restore-ExplorerWindow</maml:name>
        <command:parameter
         required="true"
         variableLength="true"
         globbing="false"
         pipelineInput="true"
         position="0"
         aliases="none">
          <maml:name>Path</maml:name>
          <dev:type>
            <maml:name>System.String[]</maml:name>
            <maml:uri />
          </dev:type>
          <dev:defaultValue>none</dev:defaultValue>
        </command:parameter>
      </command:syntaxItem>
      <command:syntaxItem>
        <maml:name>Restore-ExplorerWindow</maml:name>
        <command:parameter
         required="true"
         variableLength="true"
         globbing="false"
         pipelineInput="true"
         position="0"
         aliases="none">
          <maml:name>ExplorerState</maml:name>
          <dev:type>
            <maml:name>System.Object[]</maml:name>
            <maml:uri />
          </dev:type>
          <dev:defaultValue>none</dev:defaultValue>
        </command:parameter>
      </command:syntaxItem>
     </command:syntax>
    <command:parameters>
      <command:parameter required="true" variableLength="true" globbing="false" pipelineInput="true" position="0" aliases="none">
        <maml:name>Path</maml:name>
        <maml:description>
          <maml:para>Path to previously exported .xml file.</maml:para>
        </maml:description>
        <command:parameterValue required="true" variableLength="true">System.String[]</command:parameterValue>
        <dev:type>
          <maml:name>System.String[]</maml:name>
          <maml:uri />
        </dev:type>
        <dev:defaultValue>none</dev:defaultValue>
      </command:parameter>
      <command:parameter required="true" variableLength="true" globbing="false" pipelineInput="true" position="0" aliases="none">
        <maml:name>ExplorerState</maml:name>
        <maml:description>
          <maml:para>Custom object created by `Get-ExplorerWindow`.</maml:para>
        </maml:description>
        <command:parameterValue required="true" variableLength="true">System.Object[]</command:parameterValue>
        <dev:type>
          <maml:name>System.Object[]</maml:name>
          <maml:uri />
        </dev:type>
        <dev:defaultValue>none</dev:defaultValue>
      </command:parameter>
    </command:parameters>
```

`Get-Help` displays the following:

```
SYNTAX
    Restore-ExplorerWindow [-Path] [<CommonParameters>]

    Restore-ExplorerWindow [-ExplorerState] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    Opens an Explorer window using the information saved by `Get-ExplorerWindow`.


PARAMETERS
    -Path <System.String[]>
        Path to previously exported .xml file.

        Required?                    true
        Position?                    0
        Default value                none
        Accept pipeline input?       true
        Accept wildcard characters?  false

    -ExplorerState <Object[]>
        Custom object created by `Get-ExplorerWindow`.

        Required?                    true
        Position?                    0
        Default value                none
        Accept pipeline input?       true
        Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

I can't figure out why I'm not seeing:

```
SYNTAX
    Restore-ExplorerWindow [-Path] <string[]>  [<CommonParameters>]

    Restore-ExplorerWindow [-ExplorerState] <Object[]>  [<CommonParameters>]
```

with the xml help.

Comment: As an aside: your function won't work as intended with a positional `[string]` argument, because it is a type match for _both_ parameter sets.

Comment: However, you can fix this by placing `[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'ByPath')]` above the `param(...)` block.

Comment: Thank you for that. Hadn't run into the issue during earlier testing, but did get the "...ambiguous ParameterSet..." error and this fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<command:syntaxItem>` elements are each missing a `<command:parameterValue>` child element.

Simply duplicate the elements of that name already defined later as `<command:parameter>` child elements.

The documentation of the XML-based [MAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Assistance_Markup_Language) format PowerShell help files use is [How to Create the Cmdlet Help File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/help/how-to-create-the-cmdlet-help-file)

---

You can avoid the problem you encountered - notably the need to *duplicate* information across elements - by authoring your help files with the help of the  **[`PlatyPS`](https://github.com/PowerShell/platyPS)** module (install with `Install-Module PlatyPS`), which auto-generates the MAML XML from Markdown files that it scaffolds from a given module's implementation.

---

Note:

- The `PlatyPs` module only works with PowerShell [*modules*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules), not stand-alone PowerShell *scripts* (`.ps1` files).
- For script files (`.ps1`) / functions contained in script files, the simplest approach is to use [*comment*-based help definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comment_Based_Help) rather than external MAML files (`.help-xml`).

Comment: I read about the module, but wanted to familiarize myself with to file format fist, for precisely this level of comprehension.

Comment: @KeithMiller, this answer tells you how to fix your MAML, which is what your question is about. It also points you to a superior alternative that saves you from having to know the MAML details, but I've also just added a link to the documentation that describes those details. Let us know if you think something is still missing.

Comment: Had to do non-computer things before I could test. I had read the linked "How to..." article, which didn't have the level of detail I needed. I'm also slow editing because I'm legaaly blind. But now that i've had a chance to edit & test --- everything is great. Marking as `Answer` and upvoting...   Don't be so impatient!!! :D

Comment: Also, when I checked out `PlatyPS` earlier, I got the impression I needed a `.psm1` file. My script is just a `.ps1` file....

Comment: Sorry, @KeithMiller - didn't mean to be impatient; just wasn't sure what to make of your initial feedback. Glad to hear it helped. Yes, `PlatyPS` only works with _modules_. For scripts (`.ps1`) / functions contained in scripts, it's easier to use _comment-based_ help; please see my update.

Comment: I also forgot to explicitly say "Thank you", so thank you. I've created comment-based help before, and started to for this and it's companion function. But with fleshed-out examples, it can start to get longer than the code itself, and the zoom levels demanded by my vision issues make it easy to get lost, so I decided to learn about xml help files, and I'm off to a good start with your help. Rather than return to comment-based help, I think it's time to learn about modules! :D

Comment: :) Glad to hear it, @KeithMiller.